# How to reference controls using CodeDom into executing Form?

Tags: c#, dynamic, reference

I have WinForm named Form1 with textBox1 and MemoEdit1 on it. Using CodeDomProvider (c#) and dynamic code (from MemoEdit1), I want to change the text  of textBox1?

Is it possible? 
Typing "textBox1.text = "Tim";" to be dynamic code inside MemoEdit1. When I click on button2, below error appears:

"The name 'textBox1' does not exist in the current context".

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Assembly currentAssem = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        //MessageBox.Show(currentAssem.GetName().ToString());


        string sourceTemplate =
                            @"using System; 
                  using System.Windows.Forms; 

                  namespace Sample1 { 
                     public static class Bar { 
                       public static void Execute() {
                         @Placeholder
                       }
                     }
                   }";

        string sourceCode = sourceTemplate.Replace("@Placeholder", memoEdit1.Text);
        CodeSnippetCompileUnit snippetCompileUnit = new CodeSnippetCompileUnit(sourceCode);

        using (CodeDomProvider provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp"))
        {
            CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll");
            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
            parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
            parameters.IncludeDebugInformation = false;

            CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromDom(parameters, snippetCompileUnit);

            if (!results.Errors.HasErrors)
            {
                Type type = results.CompiledAssembly.GetType("Foo.Bar");
                MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod("Execute");
                method.Invoke(null, new object[] { });
            }
            else
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (CompilerError compilerError in results.Errors)
                    sb.AppendFormat("Error in line {0}:\n\n{1}", compilerError.Line, compilerError.ErrorText);
                MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString(), "Compiler Error");
            }
        } 
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add some of your code and produce an example of something that you've tried and hasn't worked.  Simply asking for a working solution to a vague problem won't get you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The generated class is different than the Form1 class that is hosting the generated code.  In order for your function to work you would need to add a parameter to your `Execute` method and pass in the text box.

```
  string sourceTemplate =
      @"using System; 
        using System.Windows.Forms; 

        namespace Sample1 { 
           public static class Bar { 
              public static void Execute(TextBox textBox1) {
                 @Placeholder
              }
           }
        }";
```

then in your invocation

```
method.Invoke(null, new object[] { textBox1 });
```

Comment: Edited the reply.  I didn't match my parameter name with the code you are adding in placeholder.  If the parameter and the dynamic code match it should work.  I'll have to wait until I get home to build a more extensive example on my side.  I'm curious as to why you are building this.

Comment: Hi, I want to manipulate (Change text, location etc) Controls on the Form1 during Runtime using C# language. Is it possible with CodeDomeProvider? How to reference them? Thanks.